# Cypress get text from first row and first column of the table

Tags: cypress

I have a table with multiple rows and colums, e.g.

```
ID | name | age
21 | John | 30
35 | Jan  | 25
```

I want to get the first ID from the table via Cypress and use this ID further in the code.

I tried it via

```
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > [headers="table-header"]').then(function ($el) {
    const id1 = $el.text();
    this.data = id1;
});
```

which correctly selects the first ID and outputs the ID in the console as I wanted, but after that, when I set:

```
this.data = id1
```

to have it globally, after  I do

```
cy.log(this.data)
```

*Cannot read property 'data' of undefined*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked before, but I'm struggling to find the question.

There's two things that affect it

- the test must use `it('...', function() {...` for `this` to be defined.
- `cy.log(this.data)` grabs the initial value of `this.data`, not the value set within the command - even though the log is displayed ***after*** the command.

<s>The safest way</s> One way is with an alias

```js
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > [headers="table-header"]')
  .then(function ($el) {
    const id1 = $el.text();
    cy.wrap(id1).as('data');
});

cy.get('@data').then(data => cy.log(data))
```

or

```js
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > [headers="table-header"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .as('data');

cy.get('@data').then(data => cy.log(data))
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you. But will data be recognized also outside of that it('...') step globally? Let's say I want to use that in another step in the same file.

Comment: No,  not with an alias - they are cleared between tests - at least the `cy.get('@data')` will fail in a second test. But, `.as('data')` does set a value in `this.data` which ***does not get cleared*** between tests. Also, `cy.log(this.data)` will see the ***correct*** value when used in a second test (or if set in a `beforeEach()` and used in a test). The whole thing lacks a little coherence.